# Unit testing retries with project reactor

Tags: unit-testing, project-reactor

I have a piece of code that goes something like this:

```
somePublisher
  .subscribeOn(...)
  .flatMap { x -> someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x) }
  .retry(3)
  .subscribe()
```

So far I have managed to unit test happy paths, like whether the code inside `map {...}` is getting called, using the tools from reactor-test.

Now I want to test errors and retries. How can I test to make sure `someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x)` is getting called at most 4 times when  consecutive errors occur?

Answer (score 3):

Simple way is to mock function and count its calls:

```
def 'Test retry'(){
    setup:
    someBean = Mock(SomeBean)
    def testMono = Mono.just(X)
            .flatMap { x -> someBean.someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x) }
            .retry(3)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    when:
    StepVerifier.create(testMono).verifyError(IllegalArgumentException)

    then:
    4 * someBean.someFunctionThatReturnsMono(_ as X) >> Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException())
}
```

Another one is to mock funtion to return PublisherProbe and count probe subscriptions:

```
def 'Test retry'() {
    when:
    PublisherProbe probe = PublisherProbe.of(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException()))

    someBean = Mock(SomeBean) {
        someFunctionThatReturnsMono(_) >> probe
    }

    def testMono = Mono.just(X)
            .flatMap { x -> someBean.someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x) }
            .retry(3)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    then:
    StepVerifier.create(testMono).verifyError(IllegalArgumentException)
    probe.subscribeCount() == 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it for one of my use-cases:

```
def "should retry failed action given number of times"() {
    given:
    def invocationCounter = new AtomicInteger(0)

    when:
    Mono<Void> mono = myService.doSth()
        .doOnError { invocationCounter.incrementAndGet() }

    then:
    StepVerifier.create(mono)
            .verifyErrorMatches { it == expectedError }

    and:
    invocationCounter.get() == 1 + retryNum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When all configured retries have been attempted you get an exception of type `reactor.core.Exceptions.RetryExhaustedException` which wraps the original exception thrown by `someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x)`.

This exception is an inner class that cannot be asserted directly, but the `reactore.core.Exceptions` class offers a method `Exceptions.isRetryExhausted(Throwable t)` to do so.

```
somePublisher
  .subscribeOn(...)
  .flatMap { x -> someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x) }
  .retry(3)
  .as(StepVerifier::create)
  .verifyErrorMatches(Exceptions::isRetryExhausted);


// using AssertJ

somePublisher
  .subscribeOn(...)
  .flatMap { x -> someFunctionThatReturnsMono(x) }
  .retry(3)
  .as(StepVerifier::create)
  .verifyErrorSatisfies(t -> {
      assertThat(t).matches(Exceptions::isRetryExhausted);
      assertThat(t).hasMessage("Retries exhausted: 3/3");
      assertThat(t.getCause()).isInstanceOf(TheOriginalException.class);
  });
```